# script to extract last modified files in multiple sub folder as a list in separate sub folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

batch file which can search and list all the which are last modified date( which are latest in the subfolder) in all the subfolder

below command

```
gci -rec -file | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select-object FullName,LastWriteTime| out-file D:\test.txt
```

the output gives all the files, not just one file per folder

like this batch file can move file base on the list

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do move "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"
```

Comment: Not tested suggestion: Line 1: `@echo off` Line 2: `del "%~dp0ListFile.txt" 2>nul` Line 3: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\SourceFolder" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do call :ProcessFolder "%%I"` Line 4: `goto :EOF` Line 5: `:ProcessFolder` Line 6: `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir %1 /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do echo "%~1\%%J">>"%~dp0ListFile.txt" & goto :EOF`

Comment: No need for batch file stuff. This is very basic PowerShell file & folder management using the built-in Get-ChildItem, Export-Csv & Out-File cmdlets. There are several examples shown in the built-in help files,  Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem, Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples, via the online help files, - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem --- and even videos on Youtube. --- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell+File+and+Folder+Management%27 --- So, work thru those and get back to us if you have errors.

Comment: gci -rec -file | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select-object FullName,LastWriteTime| out-file D:\test.txt, this command get all the file, but im looking to only one per folder, which is the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, this should work:

```
$rootPath = 'The_path_where_the_files_and_subfolders_to_collect_are'

# get the list of files, group them by the DirectoryName property and loop through
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Recurse -File | Group-Object DirectoryName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 1 -Property FullName,LastWriteTime
}
# write the results into a neat CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\latestfiles.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the support Mr. Theo,  script work like super dank way but had to do need modifications in the export of file as csv appear as blank, so I did Out-File D:\file.txt. And it work. 